# efficient evaluation of formula

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, mathematical-optimization, symbolic-math

Here is the problem I ran into. I have a list of evaluators, I_1, I_2... etc, which have dependency among each other. Something like I_1 -> I_2 (reads, I_2 depends on I_1's result). There is no cyclic dependency.

each of these shared interfaces bool eval(), double value(). say I_1->eval() would update the result of I_1, which can be returned by I_1->value(). And the boolean returned by eval() tells me if the result has changed, and if so, all I_js that depend on I_1 need to be updated.

Now say I_1 has updated result, how to run as few eval()s as possible to keep all I_js up to date?

Comment: Perform topological sorting of the expressions; when you modify a variable, update the dependent nodes, respecting this order.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like a breadth first search from l_1, omitting to search the descendants of nodes whose return from eval() said that they had not changed, and taking into account that you should not evaluate a node until you have evaluated all the nodes that it directly depends on. One way to arrange this would be to keep a count of unevaluated direct dependencies on each node, decrementing the count for all the nodes that depend on a node you have just evaluated. At each stage if there are nodes not yet evaluated that need to be there must be at least one that does not depend on an unevaluated node. If not you could produce an infinite list of unevaluated nodes by travelling from one node to a node that it depends on and so on, and we know there are no cycles in the dependency graph.

There is pseudo-code for breadth first search at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search.

Comment: this will not work. I_1->I_2->I_3->I_4, I_1->I_4, An breath first search will evaluate I_4 before I_3, which could give wrong answer.

Comment: @user40129 Even considering his 'taking into account that you should not evaluate a node until you have evaluated all the nodes that it directly depends on' ?

Comment: In order to keep the count correct, even the eval() value doesn't change, you still need to search the child to mark count correctly.. Hence this is a quadratic(?) algorithm..

Comment: I don't think it's quadratic. I do think it's close enough to topological sorting that the best thing to do might be to run a topological sort first and then use that ordering as the basis for everything else. There are well known algorithms for doing topological sort in linear time - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

Answer (score 0):

I just have a nested loop like this:

```
first do a tree-walk from I_1, marking it and all descendants as out-of-date
make a list of those descendants

anything_changed = true
while anything_changed
    anything_changed = false
    for each formula in the descendant list
        if no predecessors of that formula in the descendant list are out of date
             re-evaluate the formula and assert that it is not out of date
             anything_changed = true
```

Look, it's crude but correct.
So what if it's a bit like a quadratic big-O?
If the number of formulas is not too large, and/or the cost of evaluating each one is not too small, and/or if this is not done at high frequency, performance should not be an issue.

Comment: True, it is correct. However, the check "no predecessors of that formula in the descendant list are out of date" is really the juicy of the algorithm. How to do this efficiently?

Comment: @user40129 So there's only a single source evaluator?

Comment: @gbr: not sure what you mean by single source evaluator.

Comment: I meant a single source vertex in the dependency graph, that is an evaluator not dependent on any other

Comment: @user40129: "no predecessors of that formula in the descendant list are out of date" means: loop through the descendant list. Ignore any formula that is not a predecessor of the subject formula. If it is a predecessor, is it out of date? If it is out of date, stop, because you cannot (yet) evaluate the subject formula. Look, it sounds complicated, but you can get a cup of coffee, turn off your phone, knuckle down, and code it. Don't worry about big-O. Later, if you're worried about performance, profile it to see if it's worth the topological sort approach.

Answer (score 0):

An efficient solution would be to have two relations. If `I_2` depends on `I_1` you would have `I_1 --influences--> I_2` and `I2 --depends on--> I_1` as relations.
You basically need to be able to efficiently calculate the numbers of out-of-date evaluations that `I_X` depends on (let's call that number `D(I_X)`)

Then, you do the following:

```
Do a BFS with the --influences--> relation, storing all reachable I_X
Store the reachable I_X in a data structure that sorts them according to their D(I_X) , e.g. a Priority Queue 
   // finding the D(I_X) could be integrated into the DFS and require little additional calculation time
while (still nodes to update):
    Pop and re-evaluate the I_X with the lowest D(I_X) value (e.g. the first I_X from the Queue) (*)
    Update the D(I_Y) value for all I_Y with I_X --influences--> I_Y
       (i.e. lower it by 1) 
    Update the sorting/queue to reflect the new D(I_Y) values
```

(*) The first element should always have `D(I_X) == 0`, otherwise, you might have a circular dependency

The algorithm above uses quite a bit of time to find the nodes to update and order them, but gains the advantage that it only re-valuates every `I_X` once.

Comment: how does it handle the case where all children's evaluator doesn't change case? Such nodes should be skipped.

Comment: I am not sure If I understand what you want to know here. Do you mean "what happens if a re-evaluation does not change the result of I_X" ?

Comment: Sometime you don't need to evaluate every I_x,  I_1->I_2->I_3->I_4, I_1->I_5->I_4. If evaluation of I_3 and I_5 doesn't change their result, I_4 can be skipped. So evaluate every I_x in correct order is correct but not really optimal.

Comment: In that case, you have multiple possibilities. The first one being a boolean flag on each I_X denoting that the last recalculation did not change the result; or a cache in each I_X storing all values used in the lat recalculation. In both cases, any I_X that is asked to re-Calculate can check if it can skip it and deliver it's last result again without any calculations.

Answer (score 0):

If I could, I'd add links from a parent to it's dependant children, so the update then becomes:-

```
change_value ()
{
  evaluate new_value based on all parents

  if (value != new_value)
  {
    value = new_value
    for each child
      child->change_value ()
  }
}
```

Of course, you'd need to cope with the case where Child(n) is the parent of Child(m)

Actually, thinking about it, it might just work but won't be a minimal set of calls to change_value

Comment: Pretty much the same as DubioserKerl's answer

Comment: This depth first search approach also doesn't work for  I_1->I_2->I_3->I_4, I_1->I_4. If it choose to go with path I_4, it will evaluate I_4 before I_3 and get the wrong answer.

Comment: @user40129: There is a chance the order doesn't matter as the update of I_4 in your example will happen at least twice - after I_1 is changed and after I_3 is changed (need to test this to make sure though). The update only stops when the value remains unchanged.

Comment: If you evaluate in order I_1, I_2, I_3, I_4, then I_4 evaluated once, correctly and optimal. So I_4 doesn't have to be evaluated twice. The algorithm should find out this order in, hopefully, close to O(n). and call eval less than n times if possible.